# Grails Many to Many Without BelongsTo

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm

How can I make domain classes to make tables in Grails which 'share' data but do not 'belong' to the other? For example, I want to make 2 tables:

**Person Table with 2 major columns**
Name - Skills
Larry - Jumping, Laughing, Punching
Curly - Crying, Laughing
Moe - Punching, Dancing

**Skill Table with 2 major columns**
Name - Persons
Jumping - Larry
Crying - Curly
Laughing - Larry, Curly
Punching - Larry, Moe
Dancing - Moe

Deleting a Skill also removes that skill in the Person table, while deleting a Person also removes that person in the Skills table. I tried the domain class below, but when I generate views, I'm unable to enter multiple Skills per Person and vice versa.

```
class Skill {
String name
Person person
static hasMany = [person: Person]

class Person {
String name 
Skill skill
static hasMany = [skill: Skill]
```

I've looked at other posts, but the solutions often have 3 or more classes (usually Book, Author, Chapter) and seem very complicated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try removing `Person person` from `Skill` and removing `Skill skill` from `Person`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
class Skill {
    String name
}
class Person {
    String name
    static hasMany = [skills: Skill]
}
```

Grails will create a 3rd table called something like PERSON_SKILL which will have person_id and skill_id as columns. When editing what skills your person objects have, you are really editing records in this 3rd table.

Deleting a person record will delete all corresponding person_skill records for the person_id.

To delete a skill record, you'll need to manually delete all person_skill records for the skill_id first, before the skill record can be deleted.

Effectively, skill is acting as a static data table so doesn't need to belong to another domain object. I use several instances of this in my systems and Grails/GORM seems to automatically generate the obj1_by_obj2 link table for the ids.

I think your views/controllers/services can just deal with the person.skills collection (i.e. add, remove) then leave Grails to persist the updated collection to this 3rd table.

Give that a go.

Comment: I've tried that before, and I've uploaded a demo app to show the output: http://mongotest.ap01.aws.af.cm/ But the only way to have each person's skill link to a skill object (and to link a skill person to a person object) is through many to many with a belongs to. Anyway, I'm looking into MongoDB to see if it will be easier to use for such a purpose.